# How to setup Intellisense for Pyqt5 in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyqt5

In my case, it's work for PyQt4 ,

But there is no Intellisense for PyQt5 in vscode.

I installed the 'kite' (AI Intellisense).